# Подскажите пожалуйста как отправить данный XML код методом POST?

Tags: php, html, xml

Требуется отправить данный код, добавил ниже, через форму методом POST. Подскажите пожалуйста как мне это сделать? И на будущее подскажите пожалуйста, что почитать чтобы не возникало таких вопросов.

```html
<form action="https://anketa.alfabank.ru/alfaform-pos/endpoint" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<textarea name="InXML" >
<inParams>
<companyInfo>
<inn>1111111111</inn>
</companyInfo>
<creditInfo>
<reference>A0000000001</reference>
</creditInfo>
<clientInfo>
<lastname>Иванов</lastname>
<firstname>Иван</firstname>
<email>test@mail.com</email>
<mobphone>9876543210</mobphone>
</clientInfo>
<specificationList>
<specificationListRow>
<category>CRT_TV</category>
<code>#123</code>
<description>Samsung</description>
<amount>1</amount>
<price>10000</price>
</specificationListRow>
<specificationListRow>
<category>MOBILE_PHONE</category>
<code>#1222</code>
<description>HTC</description>
<amount>2</amount> 
<price>10000</price>
<image>http://www.photo.ru/product.png</image> 
</specificationListRow> 
</specificationList> 
</inParams> 
<br> 
</textarea> 
<input type="submit" value="Купить в кредит" style="float: left;">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

```
$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);

$result = file_get_contents('http://example.com/submit.php', false, $context);
```

где `$postdata` это Ваш xml 
Добавлю ответ, хоть и не в моих правилах как отправить по нажатию кнопки. Делаем html форму

```
<form action='/send.php' method='get'>
  <button type='submit'>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

код выше в скрипт `send.php` вносим.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а как сделать так, чтобы это отправлялось нажатием на кнопку?

Comment: @Garicko я вам дал направление, дальше пытайтесь разобраться но подскажу. Вам надо засабмитить форму, проверить что она засабмиченна и отправить

Comment: @Garicko примерно так как в ответе дописал